# I need to compare two strings and remove characters if they match from string one, python

Tags: python, string

I have two strings so for example:
`string1 = "abcdefga"`
`string2 = "acd"`
I need to make string one return with `"befga"`
I can replace it but if `string1` has two of the same characters it gets rid of both so for example my `string1` keeps returning as `"befg`":

```
for char in string1:
    for nike in string2:
        if char == nike:
            string1 = string1.replace(char,"")
```

Comment: Do you mean you only want to remove the first instance of the characters from string1 in the order they appear in string2?

Comment: The order of characters in `string2` is obviously irrelevant.  `string2` represents a counted set (a multiset) of characters.  Order is only important in `string1`.

Comment: I am just confirming because the characters are removed in the order 'a', 'c', 'd', as they appear in string2.

Comment: The order of characters is irrelevant in both strings. I just need to remove all the letters in string1 that match the letters in string2

Comment: @Jacob it doesn't matter what order they are in `string2`.  You are missing that.  Try reversing `string2`.  You get the same answer, right?

Comment: @Big Aus Ok, so you would be just as happy getting `"abefg"` as the answer?  You did not indicate that at all in your question.  You should edit it to emphasize that you don't care what order the resulting characters are in.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `maxreplace` parameter of `replace` to replace only the first occurrence;

> **string.replace(s, old, new[, maxreplace])**
>   Return a copy of string s with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. *If the optional argument maxreplace is given, the first maxreplace occurrences are replaced.*

```
string1 = "abcdefga"
string2 = "acd"

for ch in string2:
    string1 = string1.replace(ch, '', 1)

print(string1)
'befga'
```