# How to remove/delete characters from end of string that match another end of string

Tags: python-3.x, string, replace, nltk

I have thousands of strings (not in English) that are in this format:

```
['MyWordMyWordSuffix', 'SameVocabularyItemMyWordSuffix']
```

I want to return the following:

```
['MyWordMyWordSuffix', 'SameVocabularyItem']
```

Because strings are immutable and I want to start the matching from the end I keep confusing myself on how to approach it.

My best guess is some kind of loop that starts from the end of the strings and keeps checking for a match.

However, since I have so many of these to process it seems like there should be a built in way faster than looping through all the characters, but as I'm still learning Python I don't know of one (yet).

The nearest example I could find already on SO can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35401708/i-need-to-compare-two-strings-and-remove-characters-if-they-match-from-string-on) but it isn't really what I'm looking for.

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: How do you define an 'end of string' exactly?

Comment: provide 2-3 more examples just to clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`commonprefix` from `os.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.commonprefix) to find the common suffix between them:

```
from os.path import commonprefix

def getCommonSuffix(words):
    # get common suffix by reversing both words and finding the common prefix
    prefix = commonprefix([word[::-1] for word in words])
    return prefix[::-1]
```

which you can then use to slice out the suffix from the second string of the list:

```
word_list = ['MyWordMyWordSuffix', 'SameVocabularyItemMyWordSuffix']

suffix = getCommonSuffix(word_list)
if suffix:
    print("Found common suffix:", suffix)

    # filter out suffix from second word in the list
    word_list[1] = word_list[1][0:-len(suffix)]
    print("Filtered word list:", word_list)
else:
    print("No common suffix found")
```

Output:

```
Found common suffix: MyWordSuffix
Filtered word list: ['MyWordMyWordSuffix', 'SameVocabularyItem']
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@glhr/55705902-common-suffix